# Concatenate Fields in Dynamic SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application populated table that has quiet a few columns. I'm setting up an audit trail of changes to the data in table, my initial go to was to set up a trigger, however when the data updates it updates 1 column at a time, creating 40 rows per update, per account (example only).

I am looking to write a stored procedure that checks for changes, given the number of columns ideally would like to concatenate ALL the columns into one string, then compare it to itself for changes and create a new record if there are any. But do this **dynamically**, so i don't have to `select col1,' + ' col2,' + ' col3,' + 'col4 from table` for every column.

I've got the code that gets the column names, however i'm stuck at how to get into a `SELECT` statement, with the relevant `OR`. Using 2 tables, the source table, and the audit table to do the comparative.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(500)


SELECT @s =  ISNULL(@s+', ','') + c.name   
FROM  sys.all_columns c join sys.tables  t 
            ON  c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'table1'

SELECT @s
```

So the desired output would be (based on @s being the concatenated column)

```
SELECT @s, AccountRef
FROM table1_Source as t1 INNER JOIN
     table2_Audit as t2 ON t1.AccountRef = t2.AccountRef
WHERE t1.AccountRef = t2.AccountRef
AND t1.@s <> t2.@s
```

Comment: there are checksum(*) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql, binary_cheksum(*) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql, hope it will be enough to avoid collision in your data. If you are happy with crc32, you can just replace t1.@s and t2.@s  with binary_checksum(t1.*) and binary_checksum(t2.*) and remove @s from selection

Comment: Are your trying to check the changes inside a field or change of number of fields?